# VS2008 C++ warning LNK4229: invalid directive

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, comments, warnings, directive

I took a VS2008 C++ project written by a developper who has left the company.
When I compile the program, for each class compiled (and also for StdAfx) twice, I get the following warning:

"ClassName.obj : warning LNK4229: invalid directive '/COMMENT:@(#) $Workfile: $, $Revision: $, $Modtime: $' encountered; ignored"

The linker doesn't recognize these warnings.

Do you have an idea where is located the directive, I didin't find them in the project properties?

Thanks

Comment: Check the code for `#pragma` (specifically `#pragma comment`) directives.

Comment: Thanks Phil, but there's no #pragma comment, only #pragma once and some #pragma pack,...

Comment: Another possibility is something buried in property sheets (these would show up as `.props` files and referenced from the `.vcxproj` files).

Comment: Sorry, no ".props" or ".vcxproj" files.
However, there's a .dsw and .dsp, realated to VC++6.0 project/workspace.

Comment: So you are opening the VC6 projects/workspaces in VS2008 without conversion?  Are you building from IDE or from command-line?  Have you tried Clean and Rebuild All?

Comment: No, I have the .sln and vcproj corresponding to VS2008, and i work with that. Of course, I tried to clean and rebuild all

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the #pragma comment, located among include .h and .cpp files.
These files are not read by Visual Studio with the "Find" function, so I figured it out using grepwin.

Directive associated to the warning:
**#pragma comment( exestr, "@(#) $Workfile: $, $Revision: $, $Modtime: $" )**

It seems refers to a source code version manager...

So problem solved.

Thanks for your help Phil.